# Eigen vector centrality calculation igraph (Python)

Tags: python, graph, igraph, eigenvector

I am trying to see the function definitions for `eigenvector_centrality()`, in the `igraph` package in python, but unable to find them. I want to understand how they calculate eigenvector centrality for directed and undirected graphs. Any links to the source or the calculations used would be very helpful.

Comment: This reads like an XY problem. What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

The source code for `igraph` can be seen under https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph.

The function definition of `eigenvector_centrality` you are looking for may be under this file: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/2ceb15db7983a15e499844daddd1e1aa72cb0138/src/centrality/centralization.c
which is in `C` language.

Answer (score 0):

igraph uses [ARPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPACK) to compute eigenvector centralities. ARPACK is a general purpose package for finding eigenvalues/eigenvectors of sparse matrices.

As of igraph 0.9, you will find the source code in `src/centrality/centrality_other` in igraph's C core ([link](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/src/centrality/centrality_other.c#L552)), though I do not think that looking at it is particularly helpful. If you have specific concerns about the implementation, you should ask about them directly.

Some notes that might be helpful:

- Eigenvector centrality is well-defined only for connected graphs. The solution is not unique for the unconnected case and igraph 0.9 gives not guarantees about the handling of this case.
- In the directed case, the definition igraph uses is `\sum_j A_ij x_i = \lambda x_i` where `A_ij = 1` if there is an edge `i -> j`. In other words, it uses the left eigenvector of the adjacency matrix. However, keep in mind that the eigenvector centrality is not considered to be the most appropriate measure for directed graphs.